# How to test if an object is Annotated in Python?

Tags: python, python-typing

Consider the following code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Annotated

@dataclass
class Foo:
    x: Annotated[int, 'x']

print(fields(Foo)[0].type)
# typing.Annotated[int, 'x']
print(isinstance(fields(Foo)[0].type, Annotated))
# False
print(fields(Foo)[0].type is Annotated)
# False
```

I want to test if type of `x` field in a `dataclass` is `Annotated` type but it always return `False`. What's wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Annotated[int, 'x'].__class__`  is `typing._AnnotatedAlias` which is a subclass of `typing._GenericAlias`.
Annotations are in general a type of Alias and not tied to their original class in a inheritance relationship.

There is `typing.get_origin` which is a wrapper of the following (for this case):

```py
from typing import _AnnotatedAlias
t = Annotated[int, 'x']
print(isinstance(t, _AnnotatedAlias)) # -> True
```

Further an exact match is given through:

```
if isinstance(t, _AnnotatedAlias) and t.__origin__ == int and t.__metadata__ == ("x",):
   print("match")
else:
   print("false")
```

Which is nearly equivalent to `t == Annotated[int, "x"]`.